# @PreAuthroize has role vs requestMatchers().hasRole()

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-resource-server

I have created jwt implementation with Spring Resource Server dependency.
Here is config class:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${app.chat.jwt.public.key}")
    private RSAPublicKey publicKey;

    @Value("${app.chat.jwt.private.key}")
    private RSAPrivateKey privateKey;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.exceptionHandling(
                exceptions ->
                        exceptions
                                .authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                                .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler()));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/sign-in").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/sign-up").permitAll()
//                .requestMatchers("/hello").hasRole("ROLE_USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        var authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(authProvider);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
        var jwk = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey).privateKey(privateKey).build();
        var jwks = new ImmutableJWKSet<>(new JWKSet(jwk));
        return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwks);
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(publicKey).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        var jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("scope");
        jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_");

        var jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter);
        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source =
                new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

And I have simple controller:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

If I use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` I always return a 403 status code. But if I do the same but in the config file: `requestMatchers("/hello").hasRole("ROLE_USER")`, then it is working as expected. I have the `@EnableMethodSecurity` annotation so `@PreAuthorize` should work, but for some reason, it doesn't. Also, why do I need to add `ROLE_` in hasRole() method? I thought Spring should handle it for me.

Main question is why `hasRole()` works for `requestMatchers()` but doesn't for `@PreAuthorize`.

Here is the link to gitHub repo if needed(don't pay attention to commit messages): https://github.com/EternalSadnes/chat-app

**Update:**

Here is logs after failing request to /hello endpoint with `@PreAuthorize` annotation:

```
2022-12-05T12:27:45.300+02:00 DEBUG 6260 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /hello
2022-12-05T12:27:45.312+02:00 DEBUG 6260 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider  : Authenticated token
2022-12-05T12:27:45.313+02:00 DEBUG 6260 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.r.w.a.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@621ae24b, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ROLE_USER]]
2022-12-05T12:27:45.315+02:00 DEBUG 6260 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /hello
2022-12-05T12:27:45.317+02:00 DEBUG 6260 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Authorizing method invocation ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.lang.String com.eternal.chatapp.controller.HelloController.hello(); target is of class [com.eternal.chatapp.controller.HelloController]
2022-12-05T12:27:45.347+02:00 DEBUG 6260 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] horizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor : Failed to authorize ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.lang.String com.eternal.chatapp.controller.HelloController.hello(); target is of class [com.eternal.chatapp.controller.HelloController] with authorization manager org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager@e30a265 and decision ExpressionAuthorizationDecision [granted=false, expressionAttribute=hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
```

Any ideas on how I can debug it deeper or what should I pay attention to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, security debug logs were helpful. From them, I saw that spring at some point adds `ROLE_` to granted authorities and it results in `ROLE_ROLE_USER`. I was able to fix this just by adding roles into the token without `ROLE_` prefix.

```
String[] scope = user.getAuthorities().stream()
        .map(grantedAuthority -> StringUtils.substringAfter(grantedAuthority.getAuthority(),"ROLE_"))
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

I saw somewhere that we can prevent Spring from adding role prefixes but I have lost this article.